# ios8 crash on _updateInterfaceOrientationFromDeviceOrientation

Tags: ios, crash, ios8

Getting a lot of this crash in my logging service.  Any hints?  My app only support portrait mode.

Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread

```
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x32bfbf46 objc_msgSend + 5
1  UIKit                          0x289ba531 -[UIWindow _updateInterfaceOrientationFromDeviceOrientation:] + 152
2  CoreFoundation                 0x254d44a1 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
3  CoreFoundation                 0x2543093d _CFXNotificationPost + 1784
4  Foundation                     0x261609b9 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 72
5  UIKit                          0x289ba2f3 -[UIDevice setOrientation:animated:] + 318
6  UIKit                          0x289ba0a3 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1566
7  UIKit                          0x289b99c1 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 72
8  UIKit                          0x28a1e801 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 632
9  GraphicsServices               0x2c79d679 _PurpleEventCallback + 528
10 GraphicsServices               0x2c79d2c3 PurpleEventCallback + 34
11 CoreFoundation                 0x254e1dab __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 34
12 CoreFoundation                 0x254e1d47 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 346
13 CoreFoundation                 0x254e0349 __CFRunLoopRun + 1608
14 CoreFoundation                 0x2542e621 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
15 CoreFoundation                 0x2542e433 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
16 GraphicsServices               0x2c79c0a9 GSEventRunModal + 136
17 UIKit                          0x28a18809 UIApplicationMain + 1440
18 simplyUs                       0x00052013 main (main.m:14)
```

Comment: Did you ever found a fix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue.

Probably my case is similar to your. Some deallocated controller still received orientation notification. I had crash, when I presented controller in action sheet delegate method:

```
actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:
```

But when controller is presented inside

```
actionSheet:didDismissWithButtonIndex:
```

And everything works fine now. I think we should present controller in window, when this window is on top. So all alert views/action sheet windows should be dismissed before presenting controller in iOS8. Otherwise it still receives orientation notifications.

Answer (score 0):

It would assist if you had more of the crash-related information in addition to the crash back trace.  I suspect the problem is with messaging deallocated objects; a tell-tale example of this is crashing from a NSNotification.  You might try enabling zombies (the diagnostics tab within the Edit Schema) which can determine if this is the case.

To double-check orientation support, I recommend setting breakpoints in the methods explained in https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html
if you have implemented them at all.

One last caveat is that in iOS 8, they fixed some key methods which had in previous iOS versions erroneously ignored the current orientation such as Status Bar height/width
 [`UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height`

This means lots of code, including code from third party libraries, had code to workaround the original problem and that code now needs to be disabled in iOS 8.  Code would for example hook from logic like looking to see if status bar height was huge and conclude the system was in landscape.